# Kubernetes Ingress and Service object

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment which is WEB API. I apply it to Kubernetes. Then add `service.yml` file to expose it. It is working. I have 12 microservices. All of them have service and deployment .yaml files.

So what is Ingress controller. Why should I use it?

(Except sidecar proxy like istio. Its perfect for resilince and metrics.)

[image]

Comment: How are you exposing via services? Using nodeports? An ingress acts as a single entry point to the cluster. It does load balancing, tls termination, sometimes authentication, and other things depending on the ingress implementation.

Comment: yes nodeports. Actually I new at k8s . I use docker for years. But I interested Infra side. I  have microservices which is dockerized. At the begining It was easy to handle containers. But I have 12 container now. Every service has its own resilince pattern(retry,circiut breaker,cache ...). I want to make with linkerd or istio. and replica sets are awsome. With grafana or prom. I can config scale settings.

Comment: I have api gateway Ocelot. Why sould I need single entry point ?

Comment: With an API gateway, you do have a single entrypoint. An ingress would allow you to manage that entrypoint as a k8s resource.

Comment: I already have Api Gateway with  Ocelot. When I want to deploy on k8s Shouldn't I use Ocelot ?

Comment: I added my diagram.

Comment: Based on the diagram, you seem to have a front-end application talking to the API gateway. You can use an ingress to expose that front-end application outside, remove the API gateway completely and use the backend services directly. If you need to expose the services as well, you can use that ingress to expose them too. There are many possibilities here. This is one way of doing it among many other possibilities.

Comment: Here is an interesting read about node ports. https://oteemo.com/2017/12/12/think-nodeport-kubernetes/ . It may give you ideas why you should/shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the Ingress resource to work, the cluster must have an **ingress controller** running. The controller can be for example Nginx Ingress Controller and it can be [adjusted in various ways](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#contents). After you have deployed the controller, all you need is an Ingress resource object deployed in K8s.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-sample
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

`service.name: web-api` is the place where you specify link between the ingress and the service.

Comment: I have Ocelot Api Gateway Service for single entry point.Why should I use Ingress controller?